# ArrayList IndexOutOfBoundsException even though handled

Tags: java, arraylist, exception, indexoutofboundsexception

I have a method which tries to get the current message in an arraylist of mesages and if there are none then it returns null, however I get an index out of bounds exception and I can't understand why

```
public Message getCurrent() {
    if(this.size() <= 0) {
        return null;
    }else {
        return this.get(currentMessageIndex);
    }

}
```

The following calls the above method in another class and throws the exception:

```
public void run() {
    while (running) {
        //Message msg = clientQueue.getLast(); // Matches EEEEE in ServerReceiver
        Message msg = clientQueue.getCurrent();
        System.out.flush();
        if (msg != null) {
            if (msg.getSent() == false) {
                client.println(msg);// Matches FFFFF in ClientReceiver
                client.flush();
                msg.setSent();

            }
        }
    }
    return;
}
```

Comment: Are you extending an ArrayList ? if so I think you should really question why  that is required...

Comment: Looks like you are running this in multi threaded environment. what are you referring it as this.size ?

Comment: where is it handled and where is the error message?

Comment: @notionquestthe size of the arraylist of messages

Comment: Looks like you are running this in multi threaded environment. Unless you show us how you are using `clientQueue` when adding/removing and getting messages from it you will only get speculative answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public Message getCurrent() {
if(this.size() <= 0) {
    return null;
}else {
    return (this.size() > currentMessageIndex) ? this.get(currentMessageIndex) : null;
}}
```

> Can you try with this, I have handled fail over case.

Answer (score 0):

Just use

```
this.size()-1
```

Instead of

```
this.size()
```

Comment: How is this going to help avoiding the error OP is having?

Comment: Use if(this.size!=0)

Comment: The current `if(this.size() <= 0)` check will handle empty size. Although It 
 is pointless to check for  negative size but nerveless the code is still valid.